# Having problems cloning git repo into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm trying to help my son open his school project in Eclipse at home and we keep running into a problem trying to clone the project from Git.  I can clone it via the command line, but when I try to do it within Eclipse like he was instructed, we get the following error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2017-05-31 08:20:27.434
!MESSAGE https://github.com/SovietTesla/RogueLikeTest.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/SovietTesla/RogueLikeTest.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/SovietTesla/RogueLikeTest.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:202)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.JDKHttpConnection.getResponseCode(JDKHttpConnection.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:469)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
```

I've checked and http.sslVerify is set to false in the configuration.  I regularly use git for work, but I don't use Eclipse unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe egit (libgit2) is not honoring "http.sslVerify"?

Comment: What about cloning a project from `GIT` command line and importing it in Eclipse?

Comment: I tried that, but the workspace isn't showing up in Eclipse?  It looks like it opens up the project and everything, but it's empty (ie. the windows are all blank including the explorer).  You can open up a specific java file from the project, but my son had a blank look on his face when I showed him.  I know he has no problems at school, but was trying to get the project up and running at home so he can work on it.